# Graph has vertices labelled with an integer that describes how much snow on it, avalanche occurs if this number is > degree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

Context of problem (too long for title): A graph has vertices, each labelled with an integer that describes how much snow is at that point. If the amount of snow is greater than its degree, an avalanche occurs and 1 unit of snow rolls down to all adjacent vertices.

The problem description is above (I didn't include the actual prompt because after doing some reading I'd like to actually apply it here). It's a computer science question I am doing for practice, and I am wondering if there is a math topic related to this sort of labelled graph thing. Specifically, since part of the problem requires me to calculate the amount of snow on each vertex after some amount of time, I am wondering whether there is a shortcut to this, maybe if the states of the vertices repeat. It would be helpful if anyone knew what this topic was called so I could research a bit about it.

Update: just to clarify, the graph can have any edges as long as it is connected.

Comment: Can you see what remains constant?, Can you use that?

Comment: @h-squared of course, the total amount of "snow" always remains constant, because the avalanches just transfer snow between vertices. Also, I know that I can ignore avalanches between two points that both have more snow than their degree, at least for that specific pair of vertices, because the +snow/-snow will cancel out. But I am stuck on large graphs where there are a lot of vertices that do not avalanche.

Comment: There is one more thing that remains constant,  the sum clockwise distance of each unit of snow from a given vertex remains the same, example 5 vertices, lets say vertice 1 has most of the snow, then 1 unit goes to vertex 2 and 1 unit of snow goes to vertex 5, Now $+1-1=0$ Can you use this?

Comment: @h-squared sorry, I'm not sure I understand. In your example case, which edges are there between vertices, and how much snow is on each vertex?

Comment: Lets say we have 5 vertices, and they have snow in this order $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5)$ as $(3,9,4,1,2)$,  It is clear that $v_2$ has the highest $9$ units of snow. Now count the clockwise distance of each unit of snow from $v_2$, $v_1$ has $3$ units of snow and is at $4$ clockwise distance, so this distance is  $4+4+4=4\cdot 3$, similarly for $v_3$, $4$ units of snow and $1$ distance clockwise, so distance sum$=4$, sum this for all vertices and add to get total sum, this should come as $24$ for this case. When an avalanche occurs $1$ snow goes anticlockwise, $1$ goes clockwise,

Comment: So the clockwise distance sum remains the same

Comment: @h-squared ah, I forgot to clarify in the problem. The vertices are not necessarily in a ring. They are all connected, but this could be in any way from a tree to a complete graph. But considering this, do you think there would be a way to color the graph to find an invariant?

Comment: If we know that the graph is bipartite, (can be partitioned into $2$ disjoint sets), we can choose any arbitrary vertex, colour it red, and colour its neighbours blue, and repeat